# Casimir effect - distance dependence

Tags: condensed-matter, casimir-effect

If one decreases the distance between the two plates in a Casimir configuration, the Casimir pressure is getting stronger. Can somebody give me an inuitive explanation why this is the case?

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly speaking, the Casimir effect occurs because the spacing between the plates is so small that it excludes electromagnetic waves from occupying that space. This exclusion process goes away for large spacings (EM waves have no difficulty getting in there) and gets stronger as the spacing gets progressively smaller (EM waves can't easily squeeze themselves into the gap anymore). Since there are lots of EM waves surrounding the outside surfaces of the two plates and fewer of them in the gap, the plates experience a net force pressing them together when the gap gets really, really small and you get the Casimir effect.